# RStudio: Help on Linear Mixed Models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, linear-model, linear

I am a beginner in linear mixed models on RStudio and would like some advice on what I would like to do with my data. I work in the field of cognitive neuroscience and my research focuses on understanding face processing in adults. We measure face processing using eye-tracking measures (here pupil dilation) and a paradigm using social (images and videos of real faces and avatars) and non-social (objects) stimuli.

I would explore if the physiological engagement, indexed by pupil diameter variations, is caused by the motion. To do that, we quantified the motion amount for each video by a coefficient. My data set consists of 7 variables (participant, movements, actors/actresses, categories, movement coefficient, and pupil dilation) with 1320 observations.
Categories, movements, and actors/actresses describe my stimuli:

- categories are broken down into 3 components: object (non-social stimulus), avatars, and real faces (social stimulus)
- movements are broken down into 3 components: static, micro, and macro movement
- actors/actresses: there are 4 videos (2 actors+2actresses) per category per movement

I was thinking that a LMM would be a good analysis to answer my question, as I can consider the fixed effect and random effect but I am a bit lost about the model's writing... I tried random effect for a particular participant to allow the deviations of the intercept of that participant's pupil dilation from the population. In addition, I was thinking to add another random effect for a particular motion coefficient where the deviations in the ordinate of the pupil dilation of the motion coef in question from the full motion coefficient sample.

So I tried multiple models like this, to see which one best fit to explain my data (package lme4, lmer function) :

1. modela <- lmer(pupil_dilation ~ categories*movements*actors + (1 | participants) + (1 | motion_coef), data = data, REML = FALSE)
2. modelb <- lmer(pupil_dilation ~ categories+movements+actors + categories:movements:actors + (1 | participants) + (1 | motion_coef), data = data, REML = FALSE)
3. modelc <- lmer(pupil_dilation ~ categories+movements+actors + (1 | participants) + (1 | motion_coef), data = data, REML = FALSE)
4. modeld <- lmer(pupil_dilation ~ categories + movements + (1 | participants) + (1 | motion_coef), data = data, REML = FALSE)
5. modele <- lmer(pupil_dilation ~ categories + (1 | participants) + (1 | motion_coef), data = data, REML = FALSE)

*For your information: categories, movements, actors, motion_coef, and participants were converted as factors.*
Here IDK if these models make sense, notably with my random effects.

So few questions come to my mind:

1. Is LMM a good way to answer my question?
2. Do I have to normalize my data before starting my LMM?
3. Are the models above seem consistent according to my research question?

I hope I was clear about my description. Also, I am sorry if I didn't explain well about the LMM but as I am new I tried my best!

Thank you all in advance for your precious help!
Camille

Comment: *"So I tried multiple models like this, to see which one best fit to explain my data"* Is this your research question or is it *"explore if the physiological engagement, indexed by pupil diameter variations, is caused by the motion."*? For the latter it is better to do it separately from the former, otherwise you risk [data dredging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging). You can try multiple models, but you should report about it and discuss and motivate it.

Comment: A relevant consideration for arguing whether or not the 'linear' model is applicable is whether your research design is 'balanced', ie. whether you have all different combinations of factors equally represented. If this is not the case, then the interpretation of the results with a linear model might be different from what one would interpret with other models.

Comment: How are movement coefficients and movement category different? Can you have micro movements with a large coefficient and macro movements with a small coefficient? What is the coefficient when the movement category is static? Do these two factors correlate?

Comment: Hello @SextusEmpiricus, thank you for considering my questions! I will answer post by post. About your first comment: my research question is "does the physiological engagement, indexed by pupil diameter variations, caused by the motion?". What you suggest is to try different LMMs with different fixed effect (categories, movement and actors/actresses OR motion_coef only?)

Comment: About your second comment: I think you clearly pointed out the difficulties I encountered with my LMMs analysis. In fact,  the motion_coefficient represent both the categories (object, avatars and real faces), the movement category (static, micro and macro) and the actors/actresses variables (the 2 actresses and 2 actors don't have the same amount of motion in each stimuli video). This is for this reason I tried the LMM with the motion coefficient as a random effect

Comment: Regarding your third comment: I can have micro-movements with a higher coefficient than macro-movements, because the quantified movement in my stimuli depends on the actors and actresses (as they are different people the quantity of movement is not identical according to the movements - neutral, neutral to happy, neutral to sad). When the movement category is static, the motion coefficient is 0 (only for avatars and real faces as it is static photography but for objects, they are videos with really small motion_coefficient and smaller than micro and macro movement)

Comment: I didn't check if the motion_coefficient and the category correlates but I've already checked the correlation between pupil dilation and motion_coefficient (one correlation by category) by performing a Pearson's correlation on JASP. Rho_Objects = 0.065 (p=0.220); Rho_RealFaces = 0.052(p=0.255)